# DLL load failed when importing cv2 on Python using Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, opencv

I have installed OpenCV using Anaconda but when I'm trying to run a python code on Visual Studio platform in Windows 10, the import CV2 doesn't function and it shows me "DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found". I was wondering if any could advise me to sort out the problem?

Comment: Latest Anaconda with Python 3.7? Try to add C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: Anaconda with 3.6 I will try this but is it okay if the Anaconda3 folder is not already exist on C drive?

Comment: I tried yours one and also tried this C:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda3\Library\bin but neither work with me. Do you have another suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

Did you [specify the conda environment to run your program in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-environments-in-visual-studio)? (Naturally, this should be the environment that you installed `opencv` into)

Comment: Yes I did but the dll fail still exists although the environment is setup as in the attached picture.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Yes I did but the dll fail still exists although the environment is setup as in the attached picture.